# Setting textheight or pageheight in beamer?

Tags: beamer

For my presentation, I need to avoid any content on the bottom two inches of each beamer slide.

Can I specify the pageheight in beamer to accomplish this? I know how to accomplish this in the geometry package and my understanding is that beamer specifies such parameters via the geometry package (internally), but things like

```
\usepackage[textheight=3in]{geometry}
```

aren't successful.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %[handout] to print
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newlength\leftsidebar
\newlength\rightsidebar
\makeatletter
\setlength\leftsidebar{\beamer@leftsidebar}
\setlength\rightsidebar{\beamer@rightsidebar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hoffset=-\leftsidebar
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Let me put some placeholder math in here to test whether a proposed solution really constrains the space as desired:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %[handout] to print
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newlength\leftsidebar
\newlength\rightsidebar
\makeatletter
\setlength\leftsidebar{\beamer@leftsidebar}
\setlength\rightsidebar{\beamer@rightsidebar}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{myFooterColor}{fg=black,bg=yellow}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.00\paperwidth,ht=20mm,dp=2ex,center]{myFooterColor}%
          \Huge Height = 20 mm
      \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\hoffset=-\leftsidebar
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\begin{align*}
y''-2y'+y&=0\\
\l^2-2\l+1&=0\\
(\l-1)^2&=0\\
\l&=1 \text{ is a double root}
\\
\therefore\ y(x)&=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x=(c_1+c_2x)e^x
\end{align*}

Linearly independent?
\begin{align*}
W(e^x,xe^x)=\begin{vmatrix} e^x & xe^x\\ (e^x)' & (xe^x)'\end{vmatrix}
&=\begin{vmatrix} e^x & xe^x\\ e^x & e^x+xe^x\end{vmatrix}\\
&=e^x(e^x+xe^x)-xe^x(e^x)\\
%&=e^{2x}+xe^{2x}-xe^{2x}\\
&=e^{2x}\not=0 \ \therefore\ \{e^x,xe^x\}\text{ are L.I.}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
y''-2y'+y&=0\\
\l^2-2\l+1&=0\\
(\l-1)^2&=0\\
\l&=1 \text{ is a double root}
\\
\therefore\ y(x)&=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x=(c_1+c_2x)e^x
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend providing a cleaner code with only the necessary commands. Use my code for example as a start and show your problem with a screenshot.

Comment: Yours does work, but I need the implementation in my particular context indicated by my code. There, the math just runs to the bottom of the slide, filling it.

Comment: Then you could try to figure out which specific change that you make causes the problem and ask another question. At the moment, at least for me, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

> Two inch seems pretty much! Are you aware, that `beamer` slides are
>   typically  12.8cm x 9.6cm?

I defined a foot line that occupies the space. Please have a look at the beamer manual for details about the `beamercolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{myFooterColor}{fg=black,bg=yellow}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.00\paperwidth,ht=20mm,dp=2ex,center]{myFooterColor}%
      \Huge Height = 20 mm 
      \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb2]

Comment: I pasted a good bit of math in the frame to test it and the math just overran the footer. Am I doing something wrong? See the edit to my original post.

Comment: @JohnD There are no automatic page breaks in `beamer` (apart from `allowframebreak` option -- but this is not a good solution). Maybe somebody else has a better idea.

Comment: @JohnD See my update.